# Incrementing Variable in Loop

Tags: visual-studio, less

I've got the following loop producing some styles for a tag cloud.  On the online generators it produces the I'd consider the correct css styles, however in the visual studio solution (2012) which auto produces the css it seems to hang up. (see below) the less.  Is there a more proper way to produce something like this via less that won't confuse the VS .less generator?

```
       @iterations: 10;
        @maxSize: 40;
        @minSize: 10;

        .tag-loop (@i) when (@i > -1) {
            @j:  (@i*(30/@iterations) + @minSize);
            li.tag-@{i} {
                font-size:~"@{j}px";

            }
            .tag-loop(@i - 1);
        }
        .tag-loop (@iterations);
```

Produces via visual studio:

```
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-9 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-8 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-7 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-6 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-4 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-3 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
ul.tag-cloud li.tag-0 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

If I use something like http://winless.org/online-less-compiler the following is more accurately produced:

```
li.tag-10 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
li.tag-9 {
  font-size: 37px;
}
li.tag-8 {
  font-size: 34px;
}
li.tag-7 {
  font-size: 31px;
}
li.tag-6 {
  font-size: 28px;
}
li.tag-5 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
li.tag-4 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
li.tag-3 {
  font-size: 19px;
}
li.tag-2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
li.tag-1 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
li.tag-0 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your VS uses (via Web Essentials 2012?) quite outdated Less 1.3.3 which handles variable scope quite differently, i.e. `@j` defined in the last iteration overrides all previous `@j` definitions.
The workaround to this is to calculate font-size value directly:

```
    @iterations: 10;
    @maxSize: 40;
    @minSize: 10;

    .tag-loop (@i) when (@i > -1) {
        li.tag-@{i} {
            font-size: unit((@i * (30 / @iterations) + @minSize), px);
        }
        .tag-loop((@i - 1));
    }
    .tag-loop (@iterations);
```